# Unix Script to search text files that must contain two specific keywords

Tags: bash, unix, search, grep

**SOLUTION FOUND:** (thanks to Zsolt Botykai and Mike Ryan)

The exact translation of the script below into an `awk` one-liner is:

```
find /home/data/ -type f -exec awk '/PATTERN1/ {c++} /PATTERN2/ {d++} c>0 && d>0 {print ARGV[1] ; exit 0 } END { if (! c || ! d) {exit 1}}' \{\} \; > assetsToDelete.txt 2>&1
```

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9442764/356815

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

The question is so simple but I didn't find a possibility, to create a fast script for this.

I have 100'000 text files and I need to search all those, which fulfill two conditions.

My script looks like this, but it is slow like hell... any better idea?

```
echo Searching for first criteria...
date
grep -rl 'PATTERN1' /home/data/assets/ > assets.txt
file=assets.txt

echo Now filtering for second criteria
date
for i in `cat $file`
do
  grep -l 'PATTERN2' $i >> assetsToDelete.txt
done
echo DONE
date
```

So I'm looking for a possibility to do something like this:

Search a directory and filter out all files that fulfill condition1 AND condition2 in one step. The conditions are usually pattern matchings but on different lines within the file's content.

Comment: Will those patterns be in same line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well with `awk` you can do something like:

```
awk '/FIRSTPATTERN/ {c++}
     /SECONDPATTERN/ {d++}
     c>0 && d>0 {print ARGV[1] ; exit 0 } 
     END { if (! c || ! d) {exit 1}}' INPUTFILE
```

Now you can use it like:

```
find /YOUR/PATH -type f -exec \
awk '/FIRSTPATTERN/ {c++}
     /SECONDPATTERN/ {d++}
     c>0 && d>0 {print ARGV[1] ; exit 0 } 
     END { if (! c || ! d) {exit 1}}' \{\} \;
```

Comment: It would be useful to return an exit status.  Something like: '{ exit !c || !d }'

Comment: Does this also work recursively on a directory? Means: can INPUTFILE be a directory in this case?

Comment: INPUTFILE is a file, but you can feed in files to awk in a variety of ways.  For example:  `find /home/data/assets/ -exec awk ' ...script...' {} \;` would feed all files under the /home/data/assets/ directory tree.  (the `{}` represents where each filename would end up.)

Comment: @basZero:  The output from `find /home/data` will be the listing of each of directories.  Piping this directly into awk means that awk  takes that directory listing as its input, not the actual contents of each file.  My `find` command above was one way of "looping" over all the files in the directory tree and feeding them into awk one-by-one.   Then @ZsoltBotykai's script will print out only the matching input files.  Other loops are possible -- for example the other answer uses `xargs`, which in this case would be used as:  `find /home/data | xargs awk '...script...'`

Comment: @MikeRyan Thanks for your help. when I used `-exec` it said `missing arguments`, so now I tried the `xargs` variant.
Looks good, but awk prints out notes like `awk: read error (Is a directory)`, so I tried to do `find DIRECTORY | grep xml | xargs ...` , but this does not work at all anymore... When I find the solution for my problem, I'll post it in the question of course... Many people might need this.

Comment: My current command looks like this and is very close to fulfilling my needs: `find /home/data/ | xargs awk '/PATTENR1/ {c++} /PATTENR2/ {d++} c>0 && d>0 {print FILENAME}' > test.log 2>&1`. There are still two issues with this: AWK also prints many `awk: read error (Is a directory)` and if there is a file matching both patterns, it gets logged multiple times!?

Comment: `find dir -type f` will restrict output to just files (not directories etc).

Comment: @Zsolt Botykai: the exit code is still wrong, you only set an exit code when it is predictably going to be zero. You could simply change it to zero and add `END{exit 1}`.

Comment: @basZero: The edited answer has an `exit` statement which will prevent multiple reports for the same file, and also speed up the processing of matching files, as the rest of the file will be skipped as soon as there's a match on both patterns.

Comment: @tripleee thanks, very good point. I also edited my solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this...

```
grep -rl '<ref-date>1960' | xargs grep -l '<source>true</source>'
```

...but it's not going to be blazingly fast or anything, because you're still scanning the files twice.

Comment: this one will let utilizing two CPU cores, so would be faster than calling one after another

Answer (score 0):

The exakt one-liner with `awk` doing exactly the same as the script in the question is the following:

```
find /home/data/ -type f -exec awk '/PATTERN1/ {c++} /PATTERN2/ {d++} c>0 && d>0 {print ARGV[1] ; exit 0 } END { if (! c || ! d) {exit 1}}' \{\} \; > assetsToDelete.txt 2>&1
```

Thanks everyone for helping me in finding this!

`c=0` and `d=0` are important so that awk does not print the same filename multiple times into the output file `assetsToDelete.txt`.

Comment: Why are you redirecting standard error as well? That can't be right.